# Visual Studio 17 user keyword collision (?)

Tags: c++, collision, keyword

I defined (c++) user keywords, all of them work except for 'internal' (our macro for static)

My guess is it collides with c# keywords and doesn't add it as a user keyword.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [You know the drill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfzlQ.jpg). Even if it is tempting to define some new keywords the rule of avoiding macros (or writing them in CAPS when it is not possible to avoid) should prevail.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, "the syntax coloring mechanism checks the usertype.dat file last.". I.e. this is by design.

And as the comments note, there is a strong convention to (1) not write macro's and (2) if you violate 1, to use upper case identifiers. Both would have prevented this.